# How to call jsp page onload function when action form returns errors?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, actionform

I have a JSP page which contains some components like ' From Date, To Date and Some selection criteria which will pre-populated' and an Extract button.

If I click on Extract button, It should go through some validations and returns actionErrors if any found.

But, the problem is after validation, if it fails it is showing appropriate error message but pre-populated components are getting empty.

How to call jsp's onload function to pre populate all the components?

validate method for reference:

```
  public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

    request.setAttribute("REQ_SCREENNAME", ASConstant.VDB0018);
    if (!request.getQueryString().startsWith("method=load")) {
        if (mapping.getType().equals(VEHICLE_EMISSION_EVENT_REPORT_ACTION)) {
            logger.debug("validate for ASVehicleEmissionEventReportingAction");
            if ((this.getFromDate() == null) || (this.getFromDate().trim().length() == 0) || (this.getToDate() == null)
                    || (this.getToDate().trim().length() == 0)) {
                errors.add("nullDto", new ActionMessage("lable.VDB0011.VDBMESS020"));
            }

            else if ((this.getBrand() == null) || (this.getBrand().trim().length() == 0)) {
                errors.add("nullDto", new ActionMessage("label.VDB0025.AS0001.tooltip"));
            }
            else if ((this.getStrEmissionStatus() == null) || (this.getStrEmissionStatus().length() == 0)) {
               errors.add("nullDto", new ActionMessage("error.VDBMESS033.WFE0018E"));
            }
            else if ((this.getFromDate() != null) && (this.getFromDate().trim().length() > 0) && (this.getToDate() != null)
                    && (this.getToDate().trim().length() >0))
            {

                    SimpleDateFormat sdfmt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy"); 
                    Date d1;
                    try {
                        d1 = sdfmt1.parse(this.getToDate());
                        Date d2 =sdfmt1.parse(this.getFromDate());
                        int diffInDays = (int) ((d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                        String str_DaysVal = ASUtil.getPropertyValue("EmissionFix.EmissionReportDayDiff");
                        int i_Days =31;
                        if(str_DaysVal !=null && str_DaysVal.length() >0)
                        {
                            i_Days =Integer.parseInt(str_DaysVal);
                        }
                        if(diffInDays <0)
                        {
                            errors.add("nullDto", new ActionMessage("error.VDBMESS035.WFE0018E"));

                        }
                        else if(diffInDays >i_Days)
                        {
                           errors.add("nullDto", new ActionMessage("error.VDBMESS034.WFE0018E"));
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        logger.error(ASUtil.StackTraceToString(e));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return errors;
}
```

}

[jsp page for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZH1P.png)

Comment: Can you please provide snippet of the code, much easier to help.

Comment: added validate method code for reference which will redirect to jsp if it is returning errors. thanks

Comment: Try adding on load function to body tag like <body onload="name of your function "> or you can use document ready from jquery which is triggered after the page has been loaded completely. Try the below for $( document ).ready() block. $( document ).ready(function() {     console.log( "ready!" ); });